# "It had now been two weeks since he had left the house"

Tags: prepositions, past-perfect, tense-agreement

> It had now been two weeks since he had left the house.

Is this use of *since* correct? Is the tense of the verb after it correct?

Comment: The use of *now* is odd. The rest is fine.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The sentence as it stands in and of itself has no grammatical or usage errors, but without additional information no one can say whether it says what you intend it to say. The only way we can say if a sentence accurately describes a scenario is for you to provide the scenario.

Comment: _Now_ isn't necessarily odd or wrong in the context of a narrative set in the past. Consider this: _James held his mourning in retrospect. It had now been two weeks since he had left the house._ The use of _now_ in the second sentence is just moving the tone of that bit just a wee bit closer to the character's perspective, even though the narrator is a third person.

Comment: the use of 'now' is correct when a narrator narratnig a story. otherwise 'now' can hardly fit with past tenses

Answer (score 2):

> It had now been two weeks since he had left the house.

"Since" is correct here; it indicates the passage of time.  It's the same construct as if you say "it's been three hours since I ate lunch" or "it's been a year since I've heard from Uncle Bob".

The use of "now" is a little unusual but it's not incorrect.  You might see this usage in a story relating a sequence of events -- stuff happened, he left the house, we're going to talk about something that happened two weeks later, and then we might talk about something else.  Because you start with "it *had*", you're talking about an event that happened in the past -- just not as far in the past as his departure.

For example:

> After that terrible argument he had taken his laptop, a change of clothes, and the TV remote (for spite) and stormed out.  It had now been two weeks since he had left the house and he was beginning to regret his actions.  Why, oh why had he not taken the Xbox too?  He sulked about that all week before finally going to Best Buy.

(At the end of this passage it's been close to three weeks since he stormed out, with a bit of the narrative happening at the two-week mark.)

Answer (score 0):

> "It had now been two weeks since he had left the house."

**"Since"** is correct and you would have to change the whole structure if you were to use "for".

Verb tense (past perfect) is correct use too.

> It has been...since he left.
>
> It had been...since he had left.